# How can I get access to my Firebase Realtime Database from my Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the list of my users when I update a certain field.
I want to update the score of my players (the DB structure follows)

My Realtime DB structure:

```json
{
    "users": {
         "user1": {
             "name": "abc",
             "game": {
                   "gameId": "id1"
                   "score": 123
             }
         },
         "user2": {
             "name": "def",
             "game": {
                   "gameId": "id1"
                   "score": 456
             }
         },
         "user3": {
             "name": "ghi",
             "game": {
                   "gameId": "id1"
                   "score": 789
             }
         }

    },

    "leaderboard": {
        "game": {
               "gameId": "id1", 
               "players": [
                   "playerName": ...
                   "score": ...
               ]
    }
}
```

When a user updates his score field, I want to update my leaderboard: I call `OnValueUpdate()` and I get the right values: I access the before and the after data correctly but now I want to get the entire list of my users to compare the scores and update the Leaderboard.
I've tried every method possible but when I make a query I get always `null`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initalizeApp();

export const func = OnValueUpdate(
    {
       ref: '/users/{userId}/games/{gameId}/score';
    },
    (event) => {
       const db = admin.database();


       db.ref('/users/{userId}')
         .get()
         .then( (result) => {
             console.log(result.val());  // prints null
         });
    }
)
```

I've tried also with:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

export const func ) OnValueUpdate(
    {
       ref: '/users/{userId}/games/{gameId}/score';
    },
    (event) => {
       const db = functions.database 

       // and then access the ref with db.ref...
    }
)
```

And still getting `null`.

What should I try?

---

I work locally with the Firebase emulators, everything works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you've added the comment:

> [When] I work locally with the Firebase emulators, everything works perfectly

This is probably because the local emulators do not emulate [the strict Cloud Functions lifecycle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). When a function executes, it runs the code, waits for it to finish and then immediately hibernates, or worse, shuts down. When a function is hibernated, it is severely throttled and some API requests may be blocked. If you don't properly instruct the Cloud Functions host that your function is waiting for some asynchronous task to finish, the function can be hibernated/terminated before it finishes what it was doing.

In your current attempts, you kick off some work ("get data at /users/{userId}, then log the output") but then don't return the Promise to the Cloud Function host. Additionally, you don't replace `{userId}` with the actual userId value that triggered the current run into the string `/users/{userId}`, which would simply grab a document that doesn't exist. Because of both these issues, the function is likely hibernated/terminated before the work is even started and the data is also grabbed from the wrong (non-existent) location, resulting in the problems you see.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");
const { onValueUpdated } = require("firebase-functions/v2/database");

admin.initalizeApp();

export const func = onValueUpdated(
    {
       ref: '/users/{userId}/games/{gameId}/score';
    },
    (event) => {
       const db = admin.database();
       const { userId, gameId } = event.params; // gets the userId and gameId from the path above

       return db.ref(`/users/${userId}`) // note addition of return and use of a template string
         .get()
         .then((result) => {
             logger.log(result.val()); // note use of logger instead of console.log
         });
    }
)
```

Even though the above function would work, it does not match the database structure you posted in your question. Your database would have to look like this to work:

```json
{
  "users": {
     "user1": {
       "name": "abc",
       "games": { // added missing "games" node
         "id1": { // each game uses its gameId as the key
           "gameId": "id1"
           "score": 123
         }
       }
     },
     "user2": {
       "name": "def",
       "games": {
         "id1": {
           "gameId": "id1"
           "score": 456
         }
       }
     },
     "user3": {
       "name": "ghi",
       "games": {
         "id1": {
           "gameId": "id1"
           "score": 789
         }
       }
     }
  },
  "leaderboard": { ... }
}
```

---

Additionally, you should avoid using arrays in the Firebase Realtime Database. [This blog post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase/) is quite dated but does explain the reasoning quite well. To make it easier on yourself, you should store entries into any array-like object using their unique IDs. In the case of an array of players, you would use their userId. This allows you to greatly simplify the logic you would need to add/update/remove a specific player's score to something similar to the following (where `gamePlayersRef` is `` ref(db, `/leaderboard/${gameId}/players`) ``):

- Specific player joins a game - `set(child(gamePlayersRef, userId), { playerName: "newPlayer", score: 0 })`
- Specific player leaves a game - `remove(child(gamePlayersRef, userId))`
- Specific player has a new score - `` update(child(gamePlayersRef, `${userId}/score`), 100) ``

```json
{
  "leaderboard": {
    "id1": {
      "gameId": "id1", 
      "players": {
        "user1": { // each player in the room uses their userId as the key
          "playerName": "abc",
          "score": 123
        },
        "user2": {
          "playerName": "def",
          "score": 456
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Importantly, if a user were to change their display name, you can easily update [every game they are in at the same time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data). If you were using arrays, this would be significantly more difficult.

```
const userId = "...";
const playerData = (await get(ref(db, `/users/${userId}`))).val();

const newPlayerName = "...";
const arrPlayerGameIds = Object.keys(playerData.games);

const batchUpdateData = {};
batchUpdateData[`/users/${userId}/name`] = newPlayerName;
arrPlayerGameIds.forEach(gameId => {
  const playerNameInGamePath = `/leaderboard/${gameId}/players/${userId}/playerName`;
  batchUpdateData[playerNameInGamePath] = newPlayerName;
});

return update(ref(db), batchUpdateData);
```

Comment: Even with your code I still getting "null" when I try to print the value of the user with `result.val()`